# What kind of bullet did I find in Swiss glacial ice?

Tags: military, europe, war, identification, switzerland

I found this bullet frozen in glacial ice in Switzerland. There is no visible stamp on it anymore and unfortunately did not have any precise measuring equipment with me. I can measure the size of my ice-axe to get some estimation of the caliber if that would help.

My thoughts are that it probably originates from an aircraft cannon or anti-air gun. Although there is a small ring on the bottom of the bullet, it looks too small to be a primer, so I assume this is just the bullet part, without the casing.

[image: Top down]
[image: Back]
[image: For size estimation]

Comment: It could be some lost bullet from an aircraft's [machine gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_aircraft_weapons#Guns). Those were commonplace during WW2.

Comment: That is my expectation as well, I was hoping to get a bit more exact idea of which aircraft it came from. From a Google search it appears to only be the bullet part (Ie not the casing) which makes sense that if this was shot from an aircraft during WW2, it would still be intact if it hit nothing

Comment: It might be helpful to know on which side of Switzerland you found it, so whoever you tempt to move forward with the wild goose chase can at least narrow down the potential aircrafts that fired it.

Comment: Good point, a wild goose chase it sure is :) It was found in the Rhone Gletscher, close to the bottom of the glacier and still covered with ice.

For those not familiar with Switzerland: https://www.google.ch/maps/place/46%C2%B036'02.3%22N+8%C2%B023'07.9%22E/@46.6006477,8.3833463,768m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m6!3m5!1s0x0:0x0!7e2!8m2!3d46.6006437!4d8.3855347

Comment: When you get a chance, actual dimensions would be helpful.

Comment: The shape and coloring resembles that of a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.50_BMG#Military_cartridge_types (silver/blue tip for piercing/incendiary), but it looks like there was a notch at the tip, so: Are you sure that this is *only* the bullet and not the casing? (Wiping off the dirt could help, but if it's not only the bullet, you can hardly be careful enough...)

Comment: By no means a firearms expert, but the groove at the bottom of the object looks like [an extractor groove](https://images.app.goo.gl/rEcBezSpzv1qGyHG7); that and the change of colour between the top and the bottom sections could mean that you are actually handling a full round and not only the inert bullet; the central hole at the base could be where the primer is.

Comment: It looks  not just a bullet but a whole unspent cartridge ! Be careful with it. Explosive can be inside. If you photograph it next to a graded ruler, or tell us its diameter in millimeters it will be easier to answer.

Comment: @SJuan76, on the other hand, the smooth joint between the upper and lower parts is not a usual feature for a cartridge; it's usually a stepped joint.

Comment: Marco13 / SJuan76 / Alex / Mark: 
I initially thought I was handling the complete bullet and casing, so after carefully extracting it from the ice I photographed it and disposed of it on site. I doubt now since there's no clear stamping on the back and some comparing images of aircraft gun rounds. I wiped all the rust I could easily get off.

justCal:
More accurate measurements than "estimating" it in relation to the ice pick is unfortunately not possible. I measure the ice pick last night:
My rough estimations for the bullet:
Calibre/Width: 20mm
Length: 80mm

Comment: I sent the photos to my son who has a keen interested in WW2 warplanes. His suggestion is that it might have originated from the 20mm version of the Mk151 aircraft cannon (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MG_151_cannon). There were high explosive versions of these, that would have been colored like this. This means that this was just the bullet part, but that it also contains explosives.

Comment: That appears to be more than .5 inches in diameter, so it's probably not a 50BMG round from WW2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have come to the conclusion that this bullet originated from an [M61 Vulcan cannon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M61_Vulcan). Developed shortly after WW2, and in common use over the last few decades in Switzerland. Even today the Swiss Airforce fly the F/A-18 with the M61 Vulcan cannon mounted. It is hard to place a timestamp on when the bullet was fired, given the many years of use. Based on the rust and location it was found, I can only guess that it was from quite a few years ago.

[image: Right most]
[image]